# if the derivative is just an approximation, how can it be so accurate in analysis?

Tags: calculus

In ThreeBlueOneBrown's video on the paradox of the derivative, it is stated that the derivative is "the best approximation for the rate of a change around a point" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vKqVkMQHKk, around 9:44). Given this, it confuses me as to how the derivative can be so accurate in our analysis of our functions if it is a mere approximation; for example, in determining whether a curve is concave up or concave down, the derivative is always accurate as to this matter. I am wondering if there are any instances of the derivative telling us non accurate information as to a function due to it being an approximation and not something exact, and also why it possesses such accuracy even while it is an approximation?

Comment: "A mere approximation"? How accurate do you need it to be, if not exactly perfect?

Comment: What’s the time stamp where the video says this?

Comment: The derivative is not an approximation, it is the accurate representation of the ***instantaneous*** rate of change. ***You*** if you are using the derivative to estimate the rate of change over finite non-zero intervals are using it as an approximation.

Comment: the timestamp is at 9:44

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, honestly. This looks like a genuine, legitimate question, and just because it may be obvious to you it doesn't mean it's obvious to the OP.

Comment: Maybe it's also worth pointing out that the knowledge of the derivative at a single point doesn't really tell you that much about what the function does near that point, but if you have knowledge of the derivative (or second derivative, etc.) at *every* point of a whole interval, then you can start drawing useful conclusions.

Comment: **To the Original Poster**: I think the underlying lesson here is that Math **books** are more trustworthy than Math **videos**.  If someone makes a confusing/misleading/false statement in a (published) book, it can be very embarrassing to the author.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The derivative **is** exact. It is the **best** approximation, which means it is unique. What TBOB means by approximation is the following:

> For a "nice enough" (i.e., differentiable) function $f$, at a point $x_0$, the derivative $f'(x_0)$ is the value $A\in\mathbb R$ for which the function $g(x)=f(x_0)+A\cdot (x-x_0)$ best approximates the function $f(x)$ around the point $x_0$.

That is:

1. Take the function $f$.
2. Focus on the behavior of $f$ around **one single point** $x_0$.
3. Look at **all** possible lines that you can draw through the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$. Note that this is the same as looking at all possible functions of the form $x\mapsto f(x_0) + A\cdot (x-x_0)$.
4. Out of **all** the lines observed in point $3$, take the line that, close to the point $x_0$, most closely matches the graph of the function $f$. The value $A$ of that function is defined as the derivative of $f$.

Note that $A$ may not exist, but if it does, then it is an *exactly defined* quantity. It is not some "approximate" value. It is the exact best fit.

---

That condition, "best fits the graph of $f$", can actually be defined sctrictly in terms of limits. What we demand is that the function $$o(x)=f(x)-(f(x_0) + A\cdot (x-x_0))$$ falls to zero faster than a linear function, or even more strictly, that the limit

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{o(x)}{x} = 0.$$

Comment: Would the inset portion read better as "the derivative $f'(x_0)$ is the value $a$ for which the function $f(x) = \cdots$"? (That is, adding the referent $a$.) Oh, and making the use of $a$ or $A$ consistent—unless there's some reason for the distinction that I'm missing.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, both suggestions are useful, thanks!